# How do I run an apk file on my emulator using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation, apk

I tried using the adb command prompt but it keeps saying apk not found

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
adb -s your-emulator-name install C:/path/to/file.apk
```

Or if you have only one emulator running:

```
adb install C:/path/to/file.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally run into this sometimes when I'm not paying attention. If it says "APK not found" you might be in the shell and so it's searching the device for the APK instead of the location on your computer.

Make sure you look at the prompt and make sure you haven't typed something like "adb -e shell" before you perform the install.

To install onto your emulator, the command is:

```
adb -e install /path/name/apkname.apk
```